# Import Spacy Error "cannot import name dataclass_transform"

Tags: python, import, nlp, spacy, python-packaging

I am working on a jupyter notebook project which should use spacy. I already used pip install to install spacy in anaconda prompt.

However, when I tried to import spacy, it gives me the follwing error.

I wonder what the problem is and what I can do to solve that.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-3173a3034708> in <module>
      9 #nltk.download()
     10 from nltk.corpus import stopwords
---> 11 import spacy
     12 
     13 #path where we store the txt files

D:\Python\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py in <module>
      4 
      5 # set library-specific custom warning handling before doing anything else
----> 6 from .errors import setup_default_warnings
      7 
      8 setup_default_warnings()  # noqa: E402

D:\Python\lib\site-packages\spacy\errors.py in <module>
      1 import warnings
----> 2 from .compat import Literal
      3 
      4 
      5 class ErrorsWithCodes(type):

D:\Python\lib\site-packages\spacy\compat.py in <module>
      1 """Helpers for Python and platform compatibility."""
      2 import sys
----> 3 from thinc.util import copy_array
      4 
      5 try:

D:\Python\lib\site-packages\thinc\util.py in <module>
      6 import functools
      7 from wasabi import table
----> 8 from pydantic import create_model, ValidationError
      9 import inspect
     10 import os

D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pydantic\__init__.cp38-win_amd64.pyd in init pydantic.__init__()

D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pydantic\dataclasses.cp38-win_amd64.pyd in init pydantic.dataclasses()

ImportError: cannot import name dataclass_transform
```

Comment: You can probably just upgrade `typing_extensions`, but a general way would be to upgrade to a newer version of spacy that supports a newer version of pydantic where this problem is fixed for all installs.

Answer (score 4):

You can try following codes:

```
pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
pip install -U spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

After installation restart the kernal if you are using Jupyter notebook or lab.

It does works for my end.

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered with this on Python3.7.
I had installed spacy from Jupyter Notebok cell, via `!python -m pip install spacy` command.
Shutting down and re-starting Jupyter Notebook resolved it

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows with Anaconda virtual environment. Uninstalling spacy from pip and installing it from conda did the job for me.

```
pip uninstall spacy
conda install spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm --user
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple shutting down and re-start Jupyter Notebook fix my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).